# Commenting print() breaks the Python code

Tags: python

I was faced with a very strange problem.
With print() this code works.

```py
def max_pairwise_product(numbers):
    max_1 = max(numbers)
    numbers.remove(max_1)
    max_2 = max(numbers)
    return max_1 * max_2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    print()              # <- comment of this line breaks the code
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
```

If I comment or delete the 10-th line with print() I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\maximum_pairwise_product_fast.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
  File "C:\Users\...\maximum_pairwise_product_fast.py", line 2, in max_pairwise_product
    max_1 = max(numbers)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence*
```

*Process finished with exit code 1*

I use Python 3.9. PyCharm.
I tried to launch with different virtual environments with Python 3.8 and 3.10 – the same error.
When I launch in Jupyter and Colab – it is fane – no error.

There are no issues with any other Python script. I used the installation for several months and there was nothing strange.

It is so strange that I have no idea. Could you please help me?

Comment: What is the input? Is it two non-empty lines?

Comment: Okay I am thinking maybe a mix of tabs and spaces?

Comment: The error you get is because `input_numbers` is an empty list. You could remove `max_pairwise_product` from the test completely and just `assert input_numbers, "no data"` to narrow down the problem. Actually, even easier is to test whether `input()` is an empty string - remove the split also. Get down to basics.

Comment: @Norman - the only way the split ends up with an empty list is if the result of input is only whitespace, or more likely, nothing at all.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler,  no the `[int(x) for x in input().split()]` is right. There are two lines input.

Comment: @tdelaney input is 2 lines. first is length of array. Second - array.

Comment: Is `0` and an empty second line supposed to be valid input? How are you testing this code? The error suggests you are you giving an empty second input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping to refer me in the right direction.
The reason for the error was a **bug in PyCharm**. It sent not was typed. The issue disappeared after the PyCharm update from version 2022.1.1 to 2022.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your python interpreter is working correctly and is the latest python
It might fix it or there's probably a problem with your ide.

Comment: Do you know of a problem with PyCharm that causes this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2018 or so, I found a similar strange issue in a Python program I downloaded that solved Rubik's cubes.  Basically, the program ran just fine under Linux, but under Windows it was erroring out at a certain line that looked fine.

I ran "pyflakes" on that program, but pyflakes reported that nothing was wrong.  Odd.

The line that supposedly contained the error was a list comprehension, much like your line here:

```
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

I replaced the list comprehension with a normal `for`-loop, and then the code ran fine with no errors.  Basically, if I were to rewrite your line, I would replace it with the following four lines:

```
input_numbers = []
for x in input().split():
    input_numbers.append(int(x))
assert input_numbers, "input_numbers is empty!"
```

I have no idea why the error was happening in the first place, and only on Windows.  (The version of Python3 I was using certainly supported list comprehensions; I checked.)  But once I replaced the list comprehensions with a `for`-loop, the code worked.

So my advice is to replace your list-comprehension with a `for`-loop and see if that solves anything.

I don't know if that will work, but it's worth a shot, as it seems that your `input_numbers` list is not actually being populated before it's passed to `max_pairwise_product()`.

You might even try putting the `assert` statement:

```
assert input_numbers, "input_numbers is empty!"
```

after the list comprehension to verify that `input_numbers` is truly being populated.  If it's not, then you at least have narrowed down your problem, and will now have to figure out why it's not being populated.

P.S.  I'm curious:  Which operating system(s) does the error happen on?

P.P.S.  I recommend adding input text to your `input()` calls (such as `input("Type some space-separated numbers: ")`, even if just for posting here.  Otherwise, when stackoverflow users run your code, it looks like your code is hanging.